# How to replace ST. MARY’S with ST. MARY'S

Tags: mysql, string, replace

I've varchar string stored in MYSQL Database ; I want to replace all `ST. MARY’S` with `ST. MARY'S` .
If you notice there is difference of `’` and `'`.

Comment: Why would you want to replace the proper typographical character for an apostrophe with the “dumb” counterpart?

Comment: Use the `REPLACE()` function. What's the problem?

Comment: @MartinBean when i pull data from MYSQL into CSV it gives me some junk chars while pulling ’ from DB.

Comment: Sounds like different character sets issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REPLACE` function will replace one string with another.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET name = REPLACE(name, "’", "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET name = "ST. MARY'S"
WHERE name = "ST. MARY’S"
```